# Program many buttons!

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I have 25 buttons in my Layout. What is the efficient way to know which button is clicked or to get their IDs ??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I haven't seen your UI, but unless you're coding for a tablet, 25 buttons sounds very difficult to navigate on a finger-based touch device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't get where is problem

in layout xml add onClick="onClick" for every button then in Activity ad function

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.Button1:
      break;
    case R.id.Button2:
      break;
    case R.id.Button3:
      break;
//....
  }
}
```

EDIT (coz i can't add coment to someone else answer:
@Zach Rattner

According to this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html Zach you're wrong

> However, instead of applying an
>   OnClickListener to the button in your
>   activity, you can assign a method to
>   your button in the XML layout, using
>   the android:onClick attribute

Answer (score 1):

Button implements View.OnClickListener which receives the view that has been clicked. You can get the ID as follows...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int Id = view.getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android documentation for an Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), the only way to find a view is through findViewById. If you want to do something when a button with a specific ID is set, then you will have to add onClickListeners to each button individually.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);

    private class myListener implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (arg0 == button1)
            {
                //button 1 clicked
            }
            else if (arg0 == button2)
            {
                //button 2 clicked
            }
            //etc 
        }

    }

    myListener listener = new myListener();

    button1.setOnClickListener(listener);
    button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is to declare every button with a unique *id* in XML layout file, like this:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/my_button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_button_text"/>
```

Note that you have to do this for *every button*.

Next, you can use the following piece of code as button listeners:

```
final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button1);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
               // Perform action on click
          }
     });
```

This will be inefficient since you'll be creating 25 new `View.OnClickListener` objects (one for each button), and since you're programming for Android which is a memory constrained device, it will be better to create just one listener and assign it to every button, and then check which button does `View v` correspond to.

I hope you're not going to put 25 buttons on one screen. If yes, you might want to rethink your design.